# Python XML search value from child tree

Tags: python, xml, logging

I am now working on a modification so what do I need to do if I want to search for 999 and print the whole `blub:Log`

I would find 999 by using 
`findLogIter = tree.find("999")` but how do I tell him to print the whole thing?

```
<blub:LogEvents>
 <blub:Log>
  <blub:LogTime>09/03/2017 01:02:16.3216</blub:LogTime>
  <blub:LogIter>999</blub:LogIter>
  <blub:PlugInName>blub:System</blub:PlugInName>
  <blub:EventNumber>100</blub:EventNumber>
  <blub:EventName>I processed something</blub:EventName>
  <blub:EventClass>Process</blub:EventClass>
  <blub:LogMessage><![test message]]></blub:LogMessage>
 </blub:Log>
</blub:LogEvents>
```

Output should be like this:

```
09/03/2017 01:02:16.3216,999,blub:System,100,I processed something,Process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every Log in LogEvents, find for LogIter and if that subelement has "999" text then call getItemStr() for that Log. If "999" subelement is not present, a None list will be appended. Hence, filter the result list with None.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def getItemStr(item):
    return ','.join([sub_item.text for sub_item in item])

print filter(None,[[getItemStr(item) for child in item.findall('blub:LogIter',{"blub":"Uri"}) if child.text=="999"] for item in root ])
```

If that last line throws error, You an even use

```
print filter(None,[[getItemStr(item) for child in item.findall('blub:LogIter') if child.text=="999"] for item in root ])
```

**In python 2.6 and earlier versions**, you have to register namespace explicitly like

```
print filter(None,[[getItemStr(item) for child in item.findall('{Uri}LogIter') if child.text=="999"] for item in root ])
```

Output:

```
[['09/03/2017 01:02:16.3216,999,blub:System,100,I processed something,Process,hello']]
```

Add a namespace like `xmlns:blub="Uri"` to your xml!

```
<blub:LogEvents xmlns:blub="Uri">
 <blub:Log>
  <blub:LogTime>09/03/2017 01:02:16.3216</blub:LogTime>
  <blub:LogIter>999</blub:LogIter>
  <blub:PlugInName>blub:System</blub:PlugInName>
  <blub:EventNumber>100</blub:EventNumber>
  <blub:EventName>I processed something</blub:EventName>
  <blub:EventClass>Process</blub:EventClass>
  <blub:LogMessage>hello</blub:LogMessage>
 </blub:Log>
<blub:Log>
  <blub:LogTime>09/03/2011 01:02:16.3216</blub:LogTime>
  <blub:LogIter>1000</blub:LogIter>
  <blub:PlugInName>blub:System</blub:PlugInName>
  <blub:EventNumber>100</blub:EventNumber>
  <blub:EventName>I processed something</blub:EventName>
  <blub:EventClass>Process</blub:EventClass>
  <blub:LogMessage>hi</blub:LogMessage>
 </blub:Log>
</blub:LogEvents>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get an error: 
    "TypeError: findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: No only two argument is given right! Can you please check again.

Comment: And also check if you have added the namespace to xml

Comment: Hi, I checked again and copypasted the edited XML from here and it has the same error.
test@testserver [python] $ python 1python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1python.py", line 8, in <module>
    print filter(None,[[getItemStr(item) for child in item.findall('blub:LogIter',{"blub":"Uri"}) if child.text=="999"] for item in root ])
TypeError: findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Now I am getting this error: 
File "1python.py", line 7, in <module>
    print filter(None,[[getItemStr(item) for child in item.findall('blub:LogIter') if child.text=="999"] for item in root ])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 355, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 198, in findall
    p = Path(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator (:)
I have Python 2.6.4

Comment: Have added the edits for python 2.6 and earlier versions